# react-select package not working in build

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-select

I am facing this error at build time.

When creating a build of react project react-select dropdown is not working, and we have also added some design(CSS) to the react-select dropdown.

Also I want to display error message using redux-form validation.
my error like this:https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11028434/13355530/26648d8c-dca1-11e5-9776-15c795a8fb2b.gif
**My code:**

```
class AddArtwork extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
          this.state = {defaultval: "Select material" }
        }
    GetMedium() {
       var =materialArray[];
        materialArray = [{"value":0,"label":"Select material"}
        {"value":1,"label":"aa"},
        {"value":2,"label":"bb"},
        {"value":3,"label":"cc"},
        {"value":4,"label":"dd"},
        {"value":5,"label":"ee"},
        {"value":6,"label":"ff"},
        {"value":7,"label":"gg"}];
         return materialArray;     
        }
    MaterialDropdown = ({ input, meta ,options}) => {
    return (<div className="react-select">
            <Select
            {...input}
            onBlur={() => input.onBlur(input.value)}
            placeholder={this.state.defaultval}
            name="material"
            options={this.GetMedium()}
            />
            {   
              this.renderError(meta)
            }
            </div>);
}


render(){
 return (<form>
   <Field
     id="material"
     name="material"
     component={this.MaterialDropdown}/>
  </form>)
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put this div twice?
`return (<div className="react-select"><div className="react-select">`

Comment: You have a lot of problems in your code: 1) You use function component with `this.state`, which can only be used in a Class component. 2) You have two opening tags and one closing tag of `<div>` 3) Either you have unreasonable use of `this` or you didn't put all your code here. etc.

Comment: no, its my mistake...now check it and  please suggest me...

Comment: Do you want to render error instead of selected element?

Comment: no i am not able to select an element in react build(npm run build) .like this https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11028434/13355530/26648d8c-dca1-11e5-9776-15c795a8fb2b.gif

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading correctly you are using `redux-form`. The props for your `MaterialDropdown` are wrong. `redux-form` does not wrap the props it gives to the component into another object. They are directly available from the props object:

```
MaterialDropdown = ({value, onChange, ...props}) => {

    /* ... */

    <Select
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        { ... }
    />

    /* ... */
}
```

The [documentation](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/#props) provides a list of props that are being passed directly to your component.